# How to change system view icons/style, functionality on android?

Tags: android, android-source, multi-window, system-views

[image]

How to change view and functionality of multiwindow form (picture 1) like that on a Samsung (picture 2)?

[image: That is custom samsung view of multiwindow form]

Do we need a launcher (just a specific system change) or do we need to compile a new ROM (if ROM, then where do we need to change the code and view)?

I tried to find a section of the system where the design and window functions are regulated in the multiwindow/freeform mode, but it did not work out. How do you think what part of the code is responsible for the style and elements of this "app header" (panel with button close and others)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Android **Runtime Resource Overlay** (aka RRO).